# How to read XML with python ElementTree when there are multiple entries in each element

Tags: python, xml, pandas, elementtree

*edited to include some extra information*

I have a some data in XML format that I have managed to parse using `ElementTree` in Python. In each row of the main data there is a tag called `volume` and then a set of data which I then put into an array (which I later save as a pandas dataframe). The issue I'm having is I need to know the name of the entries which I'm calling field names (i.e. [`message`, `messagetimestamp`,`settlementdate`,`settlementperiod`,etc...] to be able to call the data.

I want to use some code to tell me what that list of field names is instead of manually inputting them. I may have my XML terminology wrong here but the data looks like the attached image.

XML as text:

```
<response xmlns="http://www.netareports.com/backend/realtime" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.netareports.com/backend/realtime http://www.netareports.com/backend/realtime.xsd" status="1" timestamp="2021-03-19T16:37:23">
<periodacceptedvolume message="BMRS.DISPTAV" messagetimestamp="2020-11-30T01:52:32" settlementdate="2020-11-30T00:00:00" settlementperiod="3" bmunitid="E_GYAR-1" bidofferpairnumber="-1" offervolume="0" bidvolume="-44.75" taggedoffervolume="0" repricedoffervolume="0" originallypricedoffervolume="0" taggedbidvolume="-44.531" repricedbidvolume="0" originallypricedbidbolume="-43.69"/>
<periodacceptedvolume message="BMRS.DISPTAV" messagetimestamp="2020-11-30T01:52:32" settlementdate="2020-11-30T00:00:00" settlementperiod="3" bmunitid="T_DAMC-1" bidofferpairnumber="1" offervolume="240" bidvolume="0" taggedoffervolume="240" repricedoffervolume="0" originallypricedoffervolume="0" taggedbidvolume="0" repricedbidvolume="0" originallypricedbidbolume="0"/>
<periodacceptedvolume message="BMRS.DISPTAV" messagetimestamp="2020-11-30T01:52:32" settlementdate="2020-11-30T00:00:00" settlementperiod="3" bmunitid="T_DIDCB6" bidofferpairnumber="1" offervolume="220" bidvolume="0" taggedoffervolume="220" repricedoffervolume="0" originallypricedoffervolume="0" taggedbidvolume="0" repricedbidvolume="0" originallypricedbidbolume="0"/>
<periodacceptedvolume message="BMRS.DISPTAV" messagetimestamp="2020-11-30T01:52:32" settlementdate="2020-11-30T00:00:00" settlementperiod="3" bmunitid="T_DINO-6" bidofferpairnumber="-1" offervolume="0" bidvolume="-2.592" taggedoffervolume="0" repricedoffervolume="0" originallypricedoffervolume="0" taggedbidvolume="-2.592" repricedbidvolume="0" originallypricedbidbolume="0"/>
<periodacceptedvolume message="BMRS.DISPTAV" messagetimestamp="2020-11-30T01:52:32" settlementdate="2020-11-30T00:00:00" settlementperiod="3" bmunitid="T_MEDP-1" bidofferpairnumber="1" offervolume="170" bidvolume="0" taggedoffervolume="170" repricedoffervolume="0" originallypricedoffervolume="0" taggedbidvolume="0" repricedbidvolume="0" originallypricedbidbolume="0"/>
```

the code I'm using to read it is:

```py
    import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
    import urllib.request

    url = #not included as it includes a password but the XML data is copied from the url
    download = urllib.request.urlopen(url).read()
    tree = ET.fromstring(download)

    fieldsV=['message','messagetimestamp','settlementdate','settlementperiod','bmunitid','bidofferpairnumber','offervolume','bidvolume','taggedoffervolume','repricedoffervolume','originallypricedoffervolume','taggedbidvolume','repricedbidvolume','originallypricedbidbolume']
    data = []
    for child in tree:
        data.append([(child.get(name) or '') for name in fields])
```

this works fine but `fields` is a list that I am manually inputting and I want to generate the list using code so I can apply it to other similar XML files. Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Please provide the XML as text, not as an image.

Comment: Also ensure that your posted code is complete and actually runs (please see [mcve]).

Comment: Is there already a dataframe with fields extracted from the XML and include all the fields you want to process ?   If yes, you can get the column labels by pandas easily.  If no, the question is not related to pandas.

Comment: What you refer to as "entries" or "field names" are **attributes** in XML terminology. The attributes of an `Element` object are stored in its `attrib` property. https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.Element.attrib

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that all child elements of the XML root, the `periodacceptedvolume` elements in this case, contains the same list of attributes, you can just get one sample of that element and read list of attribute names from there:

```
....
tree = ET.fromstring(download)

sample_node = tree.find('*')
fieldsV=[a for a in sample_node.attrib]
....
```

Comment: @user15434516: if this solved your problem, mark the answer as accepted.